# Make a specific URL redirect to the correct folder using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

I was wondering if it would be possible to redirect a `URL` specifically set inside `.htaccess` to redirect to the correct folder where my application files are located? What I did so far in my `.htaccess` file looks like this,

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteBase /mainfolder/cakephpfolder/

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

and what I would like is when I use this url `http://www.mysamplesite.org/desired/url` it will use the files which are located in `/mainfolder/cakephpfolder/`. Basically, I want to mask my previous my url which looks like `http://www.mysamplesite.org/mainfolder/cakephpfolder` and make it look like with my desired url. Is that possible? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
RewriteRule ^desired/url$ /mainfolder/cakephpfolder/ [NC,L]
```